# C++ replace string

Tags: c++

So I have a problem, I'm trying to create a program that will get one or more numbers from an user, then user will type argument A & argument B. Those arguments will be the position for replacing numbers in a string.

So if user types in: 123456789, argument A: 2, argument B: 5.

```
output: 153426789
```

I've been trying to do it in every way I know, I've been searching internet for a while now, but nothing.. I only need replace function example, that's it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've been trying to do it with this function:

> void myReplace(std::string& str, const std::string& oldStr, const
>   std::string& newStr) {   size_t pos = 0;   while((pos =
>   str.find(oldStr, pos)) != std::string::npos)   {
>        str.replace(pos, oldStr.length(), newStr);
>        pos += newStr.length();   } }

With this function aswell:

broj is a string (number), pos1(arg A) & pos2(arg B) is a char (tried it with int, string);

> replace(broj.begin(), broj.end(), broj.at(pos1), broj.at(pos2));

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried str.replace method, something from C language (thought it has to be written in C++ - it's a homework).. I tried some custom functions / snippets..

Comment: @user3478522 post the code of what you've tried (by editing your question and adding it), don't merely infer it from a high level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the original string as a `std::string`, then use the built in `find_first_of` and `erase` methods available through C++ to easily obtain your goal.  See this reference for more: [std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Based on the OP feedback below, this sample has been modified to show how to use the [std::basic_string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) function.  The code sample does not use the `algorithm` library, since that is not used now.  The `std::string` functions are being used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
    std::string s = "123456789";
    std::cout << s << endl;

    //
    // Erase the first occurrence of "2", leaving the rest of the string 
    // alone.
    //
    s.erase(s.find_first_of("2"), 1); 
    std::cout << s << endl;

    //
    // Erase the first occurrence of '5', leaving the rest of the string 
    // alone.
    //
    s.erase(s.find_first_of('5'), 1); 
    std::cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think this would erase all the 2's and 5's, I'm looking to replace those numbers on position 2 and position 5.

So if there's 1845723, arg A: 2, arg B: 7. Output: 1345728

Comment: @user3478522 You will have to be more clear about this kind of thing in the question.  Regardless, there is always a method to the achieve removal of the first occurrence.  I am updating my post to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah sorry :) Just pointing out to you. Anyway - Thanks for your help, I rly appreciate it.

Comment: @user3478522 If this has been helpful, be sure to vote.

Comment: There's really no need to document your edit history. Just provide your answer in the best form possible, as relevant to the question as possible. Anything else is just clutter. If someone, for some reason, wants to see the edit history, StackOverflow automatically keeps track of it.